# Problems with publishing VSIX on Gallery

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, sdk, vsix

I want to publish an upate to my VSIX package to VS Gallery. I edit my source.extension.vsixmanifest and increase the version-number. Then I build and log in to gallery.

There I click on "Edit" and then on "Change" in the Upload-Section. Then I select the currently builded VSIX and proceed.

The new version is shown in Gallery. When I now go to extensions in VS, now update is avaialble. But if I search for my Extension Online in the VS-Windwo it shows the new version-number but display the green "already-installed"-icon on this solution although this is not true because an old version is installed.

I already checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997169.aspx) but this will not work for me. They are claiming a file source.extension.manifest (the ending is different from mine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! It wasn't my fault but I was to impatient! The upgrade seems to take a while. After my last try the message should up in Visual Studio. Sorry for inconvenience!